# New Grails 2.3 App gets created with ForkedTomcatServer.groovy errors

Tags: java, grails, grails-tomcat-plugin

When I create a new "Grails Project" in GGTS-3.3.0 with Grails 2.3, I get several errors in ForkedTomcatServer.groovy. These are the errors I get:

> Groovy:[Static type checking] - No such property: version for class:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginInfo   ForkedTomcatServer.groovy   /testapp/.link_to_grails_plugins/tomcat-7.0.42/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/fork    line
>   165
>
> Groovy:[Static type checking] - No such property: descriptor for
>   class:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginInfo   ForkedTomcatServer.groovy   /testapp/.link_to_grails_plugins/tomcat-7.0.42/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/fork    line
>   166

These are the lines of code referenced in the errors:

```
GrailsPluginInfo info = GrailsPluginUtils.getPluginBuildSettings().getPluginInfoForName('tomcat')
String jarName = "grails-plugin-tomcat-${info.version}.jar"
File jar = info.descriptor.file.parentFile.listFiles().find { File f -> f.name.equals(jarName) }
```

I have not made any changes whatsoever. I just clicked `File -> New -> Grails Project` and the output has these errors. I have made several different projects and they all generate the same way.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this issue you should install Groovy 2.1. In GGTS the Groovy 2.1 is available from the dashboard. This solved my the problem.

Comment: This solved my issue - I used the Eclipse Level 4.3 and Release update site http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/. In the eclipse menu select Help --> Install New Software and add the URL listed below. 

Thanks to petvoj

Comment: This worked perfectly. From the Dashboard: Install Extension -> Select Groovy 2.1 -> Click the Install button -> Restart GGTS

Answer (score 5):

From 2.3.0 [Latest News](http://grails.org/news) updated yesterday

> We are aware that the IDEs will require some updates to work with
>   Grails 2.3.0. If you plan to use 2.3.0 soon, please use the Intellij
>   IDEA EAPs and latest GGTS milestone releases which include updates to
>   work with Grails 2.3.0

Comment: Ah! I wasn't aware. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I've updated my GGTS installation with the milestone updates and even nightly updates (using urls from this page: http://www.springsource.org/STS-installation-instructions), but no luck. I suppose I'll have to wait for something more official.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue to use Grails 2.3.0 with GGTS 3.3.0. After I installed the Groovy 2.1 from dashboard, this problem is gone. The same issue of the compiler version mismatch is also gone after install the latest Groovy

Answer (score 1):

Workaround. Open ForkedTomcatServer.groovy, comment out the @CompileStatic, save file. The error will disappear. Now you can go ahead and un-comment that line and the error is gone. Groovy magic!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Installtion of the Groovy 2.1 compiler sorted that out.

One of my errors said my workspace did not match the project and I could right-click and Eclipse fixed that part. Real issue was that I needed to update my compiler to 2.1.